# How to merge any parallel changes from master into my branch, without modifying master?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I got really confused with `merge` or `rebase`.

In master, at point **A**, I created a branch `mybranch`, checkout, and started working on it purely, while others keep working on `master`.

It has been a while. Today, I found `master` has reached point **B** and I still haven't finish the part in `mybranch`.

However, I would like to have all the changes `master` has up to **B**, but I DO NOT want any of my code in `mybranch` to be added into `master`.

Then what I did is

1. checkout master
2. `git rebase mybranch`

Yes, `mybranch` has all the changes from master between **A** and **B**, but I found out that `master` also has the changes I made in `mybranch`.

It seems now `master` and `mybranch` are identical now.

I thought `rebase target` is meant to put the current place into the `target`, i.e., just rebase `mybranch` based on `master`, but why it was two-ways?

How exactly to achieve my original goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your original goal you need to swap the branches around.

```
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
```

Which is effectivly the same as:

```
git rebase master mybranch
```

This means your *mybranch* will be added onto *master* while leaving *master* unchanged.

Normally `rebase` never affect target branch. You might do something else.

Alternativly you can use `merge`:

```
git checkout mybranch
git merge master
```

This will create a merge commit on *mybranch* and is a perfectly viable option.